# Data validation in user form

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a userform for entering the receiving data by the storekeepers, I want to set some mandatory fields for filling in. They are the username, part number and stored location of received file.
I am using the data of my "ref" worksheet for adding items to my combo boxes. and I forced combo box to don't accept any item out of that list. (by using field property "matchrequired" to true).
I have 4 command buttons, done for saving and closing, "add item" for adding a new item to current release note, new release note, which clear the R/N data and would ask for it again, and finally close, which closes the form.
My question is how can I force VBA to check is there any data in the "USER", "P/N" and "Location", and if at least these three field have data, then data entry be possible.
I also want to the code to be able for checking the entry of QTY field and just accepts number (between 1 and 5000 for instance).
Everything is ok with DONE button, but for the two ("add item" and "new release note") stupid errors returns. after msg box showing up the data clears, the combo's items will lost or returns error and so...

I am using "addcmbo" for adding items to combo controls. (Just for user when I am putting that here, the value duplicates in the combo index, and also after message box, the items of this control remains).

If you find any "not good practice" approaches, let me know please.

[image: 'Receiving Rear Fuse' form]

```
Sub addcmbo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Sheet2.Activate
        ' A/C data update
            For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("b:b"))
                If Sheets("Ref").Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
                    RCVNG.cmbac.AddItem (Cells(i, 2))
                End If
            Next
        ' W/B data update
            For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("h:h"))
                If Sheets("Ref").Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then
                    RCVNG.Cmbwb.AddItem (Cells(i, 8))
                End If
            Next
        ' w/C data update
            For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("i:i"))
                If Sheets("Ref").Cells(i, 9) <> "" Then
                    RCVNG.Cmbwc.AddItem (Cells(i, 9))
                End If
            Next
        ' P/# data update
            For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("j:j"))
                If Sheets("Ref").Cells(i, 10) <> "" Then
                    RCVNG.Cmbpn.AddItem (Cells(i, 10))
                End If
            Next
                Sheet1.Activate
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Sub btnCncl_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btnadditem_Click()

 '    Form fields Clear
    cmbac.Clear
    Cmbwb.Clear
    Cmbwc.Clear
    Cmbpn.Clear
'        cmbac.Value = ""
'        Cmbwb.Value = ""
'        Cmbwc.Value = ""
'        Cmbpn.Value = ""
    Txtqty.Value = ""
    txtSN.Value = ""
    Txtloc.Value = ""
    cmnt.Value = ""

'    Data entry sufficiency check
 If cmbuser = "" Or Cmbpn = "" Or Txtloc = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Fill Required Fields " & Chr(10) & "   *  User" & Chr(10) & "   *  Part #" & Chr(10) & "   *  Location" & Chr(10) & " before Save!"
    Call addcmbo
   Else:
'    Data Entry
       Sheet1.Activate
       Dim oNewRow As ListRow
       ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Select
       Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 6).Value = DTPicker.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).Value = txtrn.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 14).Value = cmbuser.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 8).Value = cmbac.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 10).Value = Cmbwb.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 9).Value = Cmbwc.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 11).Value = Cmbpn.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 12).Value = Txtqty.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 13).Value = txtSN.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 15).Value = Txtloc.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 16).Value = cmnt.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btndone_Click()
'    Data entry sufficiency check
    If cmbuser = "" Or Cmbpn = "" Or Txtloc = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Fill Required Fields " & Chr(10) & "   *  User" & Chr(10) & "   *  Part #" & Chr(10) & "   *  Location" & Chr(10) & " before Save!"
    Else:
'    Data Entry
    Sheet1.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Select
        Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 6).Value = DTPicker.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).Value = txtrn.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 14).Value = cmbuser.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 8).Value = cmbac.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 10).Value = Cmbwb.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 9).Value = Cmbwc.Value
        oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 11).Value = Cmbpn.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 12).Value = Txtqty.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 13).Value = txtSN.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 15).Value = Txtloc.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 16).Value = cmnt.Value
Unload Me
End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnnewrn_Click()
Dim oNewRow As ListRow
'    Form fields Clear
    txtrn.Value = ""
    cmbac.Clear
    Cmbwb.Clear
    Cmbwc.Clear
    Cmbpn.Clear
    cmbac.Value = ""
    Cmbwb.Value = ""
    Cmbwc.Value = ""
    Cmbpn.Value = ""
    Txtqty.Value = ""
    txtSN.Value = ""
    Txtloc.Value = ""
    cmnt.Value = ""

'    Data entry sufficiency check
If cmbuser = "" Or Cmbpn = "" Or Txtloc = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Fill Required Fields " & Chr(10) & "   *  User" & Chr(10) & "   *  Part #" & Chr(10) & "   *  Location" & Chr(10) & " before Save!"
    Call addcmbo
Else:
'    Data Entry
    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Select
    Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 6).Value = DTPicker.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 7).Value = txtrn.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 14).Value = cmbuser.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 8).Value = cmbac.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 10).Value = Cmbwb.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 9).Value = Cmbwc.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 11).Value = Cmbpn.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 12).Value = Txtqty.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 13).Value = txtSN.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 15).Value = Txtloc.Value
    oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 16).Value = cmnt.Value
End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblpn_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim pn As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Activate
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("j:j")) + 1
pn = inputbox("Type In new ''P/#'' please", "Add NEW P/#")
    Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = pn
    RCVNG.Cmbpn.AddItem pn
End Sub

 Private Sub lblTeam_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim t As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Activate
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("c:c")) + 1
t = inputbox("Type type Your Name Please", "Add name of NEW or Missing team member")
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = t
    RCVNG.cmbuser.AddItem t
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Activate
DTPicker.SetFocus
DTPicker.Value = Date
'    empty fields
   shipreceive.Value = ""
    txtrn.Value = ""
    cmbuser.Clear
    cmbac.Clear
    Cmbwb.Clear
    Cmbwc.Clear
    Cmbpn.Clear
    Txtqty.Value = ""
    txtSN.Value = ""
    Txtloc.Value = ""
    cmnt.Value = ""
    ' Combo fields add item
    Call addcmbo
    ' User data update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet2.Activate
    For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("c:c"))
        If Sheets("Ref").Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
            RCVNG.cmbuser.AddItem (Cells(i, 3))
        End If
    Next
    Sheet1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Thanks a lot, I will appreciate your help

Comment: After your msgbox line `MsgBox "Please Fill Required Fields "....` you need to put in an `Exit Sub` line so that the code stops running and it forces the user to fill the required fields.  Make sure you do this after the `Call addcmbo` line in the `Private Sub btnadditem_Click()`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `Else:` with nothing on the line after it is identical to `Else` - I'd remove the statement separator (`:`) from the end so it doesn't potentially cause issues with later edits.

Comment: Thanks,  Actually, the problem was the sequence of blocks in my code. At first, I deleted the content, before checking them, so they Always left empty. 
I changed the sequence of clearing the fields after data entry step. So, Bingo the problem solve!

Comment: Questtion un-touched for 1+ years, OP solved his own problem without details about the fix.  No useful information here.